# How to write an Element from Element Tree to a unicode string in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I have an Element filled with an XML document that I need to write to a unicode string because it contains non-ascii characters. the character(s) that it contains that isn't ascii is Â². Before I ran into this bug the script was using written like this:

```
tempxml = ET.tostring(cdadoc).decode("utf8").replace("&lt;","<").replace("&gt;",">").replace("&amp;","&").replace("><",">\n<")
```

I tried setting it to

```
tempxml = ET.tostring(cdadoc, encoding='unicode_internal', method='xml')
test = ET.tostring(cdadoc, encoding='punycode', method='xml')
print(type(tempxml))
print(type(test))
tempxml = tempxml.replace(u"&lt;",u"<").replace(u"&gt;",u">").replace(u"&amp;",u"&").replace(u"><",u">\n<")
```

where I tried the replace with both tempxml and test and it only would work with test where I had encoded it in punycode. When I tried posting it to an api, it returned a 500 code saying it didn't understand punycode, How could I set it to utf-8 or unicode?
I ended up solving the problem by using python3 which is probably the best bet because python2 is going to be deprecated at the end of the year.  Is this a good question to ask?

Comment: Please provide an example of 'cdadoc'

Comment: I'm away from the computer where i have it saved and can't recreate it from off the top of my head. I'll provide an example on Monday. Thanks

Comment: This is what it looks like:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<csmk:div csmk:class="code" npmk:nlp="off">problem: code_type: ICD9 code: V85.41 desc: Body Mass Index 40.0-44.9, adult</csmk:div>
<csmk:div csmk:class="measurement" npmk:nlp="off" csmk:field="BMI">desc: Body Mass Index value: 50 unit: kg/mÂ²</csmk:div>